# Bind entity to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, entity-framework-4, ado.net

[image]

Relation between idc=courseID

HTML of Grid view

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id"
    DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="course" HeaderText="course" SortExpression="courseID" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=dbEn"
    DefaultContainerName="dbEn" EntitySetName="userCourses">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

now grid view show only CourseID but i want show name of course.

how can show name of course in grid view instead of courseID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you have to bind "Course" EntitySetName instead of "userCourses"  and

```
 <Columns> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="course" SortExpression="name" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="idc" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" /> 

        </Columns>
```

you have to write commandText

```
<asp:EntityDataSource
   ID="EntityDataSource"
   ConnectionString="name=dbEn"
   DefaultContainerName="dbEn"
   CommandText="
      SELECT c.Name,uc.ID
      FROM Course c
      Inner JOIN userCours uc ON c.IDc=uc.CourseID"
   RunAt="server">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

More Ref : [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/578a26de-551b-473a-a294-90a309ae4460/)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488556.aspx)

Comment: idc is id for every course in table course but id in table usercourse is different. id in table usercourse user for  userID

Comment: ok you have to write join query in c# side and bind to grid. then it will work

Comment: SELECT c.Name,uc.ID
      FROM Course as c
      Inner JOIN userCours as uc ON c.IDc=uc.CourseID